# How to evaluate this integral for this type?

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

What is the skill to integrate this type of integral

$\displaystyle\int \frac{4x^n}{x^2+9} dx$ for $n$ is constant

How to use your general method to work out an example?

Comment: Let $x=3\tan t$ and then use reduction formula.

Comment: @Tunk-Fey - What is the reduction formula?

Comment: @Victor [Integration by the reduction formula.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_reduction_formulae)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $x=3\tan t\;\Rightarrow\;dx=3\sec^2t\ dt$, then
$$
\int\frac{x^n}{x^2+9}\ dx=3^{n-1}\int\tan^n t\ dt.
$$
Now, use [integration by the reduction formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_reduction_formulae).
$$
\begin{align}
\int \tan^n t\,dt &= \int \tan^{n-2}t\,(\sec^2 t - 1)\,dt \\
&= \int \tan^{n-2}t\,\sec^2 t\,dt - \int \tan^{n-2}t\,dt \\
&= \int u^{n-2}\,\,du - \int \tan^{n-2}t\,dt \\
&= \frac{1}{n-1}u^{n-1} - \int \tan^{n-2}t\,dt \\
&= \frac{\tan^{n-1} t}{n-1} - \int \tan^{n-2}t\,dt,
\end{align}
$$
where $n\in\mathbb{Z}_+$ and $n\neq1$.

Comment: But here the formula involved log not tan http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int+x%5E5%2F%28x%5E2%2B9%29+dx

Comment: @Victor I said $n\neq1$ and you use $n=1$.

Comment: Now it is n=5 on the above...

Comment: @Victor Here is the case for $n=1$.
\begin{align}
\int\tan t\ dt&=\int\frac{\sin t}{\cos t}\ dt\\
&=-\int\frac{d\cos t}{\cos t}\\
&=-\ln|\cos t|+C\\
&=-\ln\left|\frac{3}{\sqrt{x^2+9}}\right|+C\\
&=\frac12\ln(x^2+9)+K
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks a lot and thanks a lot again

Comment: @Victor You're welcome.